# Change process.env.API_BASE_URL after build in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

So, I have a react app that uses `process.env.API_BASE_URL` in api utilities to connect to API.
Till now I have been using two webpacks: local and production to set the API_BASE_URL for dev and prod.

I want to change the `API_BASE_URL` after build. Stuck at this problem because the variables are embedded into the build as values and this build is supposed to be distributed to different clients so they can have separate backend url and changing webpacks is not an option as those are already very cluttered.
Below is my webpack code:

```
const GLOBALS = {
  'process.env': {
    NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production'),
    API_BASE_URL: JSON.stringify(
      config.API_BASE_URL || 'http://127.0.0.1'
    ),
    __BUILDVERSION__: JSON.stringify(commitHash),
    __BUILDTIME__: new Date().getTime(),
    __PRODUCTVERSION__: JSON.stringify(productVersion),
  },
};
```

The below code from main.js file:

```
  console.log(
    process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL,
    process.env.API_BASE_URL,
    process.env
  );
```

logs this output:

```
 undefined
 http://127.0.0.1
 { API_BASE_URL: "http://127.0.0.1", WS_BASE_URL: undefined, __BUILDVERSION__: commit, __PRODUCTVERSION__: "latest" }
```

I have a .env file in root folder, that contains

```
REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL="http://testurl"
```

I tried this [solution](https://dev.to/eslynn/how-to-dynamically-change-your-react-environment-variables-without-re-building-55el) but it didn't work.

Comment: Your webpack code is effectively overwriting what comes from your .env file.

Comment: I would highly recommend just using dotenv https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: @SimenFjellstad can dot env work to replace/inject variables after build?

Answer (score 1):

As Simen pointed out, you cannot modify the ENV Vars after build. The result of the build is static.

If you want to avoid re-building you can checkout https://dev.to/eslynn/how-to-dynamically-change-your-react-environment-variables-without-re-building-55el

Answer (score 0):

You can not change basic env vars after build in react. If you want to change env vars on deployment, you can add `REACT_APP_` as a prefix to your env vars that react will pick up.

You can read more about using env vars in react here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: if we are only planning to distribute the build, will that work?

Comment: I would use the dotenv npm package to get env vars easily instead of "process.env."'ing it every time. Also, your API_BASE_URL will need to become REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL. I know it's ugly, but that is how react works.

Comment: Often i end up making my own utility function that slaps on the `REACT_APP_` prefix in a function called `getEnv("your_env_var")`. It usually also helps me deal with default values or throwing if needed